# Creating a unique key to combine join Tables - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, key

I am working to combine two datasets that are built without primary and foreign keys - therefore no unique key for me to join on

These are moves that will link by MOVED_CNTR_ID (CNTR_ID) and Transaction_Date (Extraction_Date) from the two tables attached

[image: LiveRTOLocationErrorsHistorical Table]

---

---

---

[image: YC Transactions table]

The issue that i am having is that not all records from LiveRTOLocationErrorsHistorical are being matched to one from YC_transactions as these columns may not contain duplicate data

Here is my Query

```
SELECT [CNTR_ID]
      ,[RTO_UPDATED]
      ,[NGEN_UPDATED]
       ,t.[TRANSACTION_MINUTES]
      ,t.[TRANSACTION_DATE]
      ,[Extraction Date]
 FROM [MIS_Apps].[dbo].[LiveRTOLocationErrorsHistorical] e
 inner join [MIS_Apps].[dbo].[YC_TRANSACTIONS] t
 on t.MOVED_CNTR_ID = e.CNTR_ID
 and e.NGEN_UPDATED = t.TRANSACTION_DATE
```

Can someone please advise on how to create unique identifying keys that i can join from

Many thanks

Comment: Presumably, you have a query that does the matching.  That should be included in the question as text.  Presumably, you are using a database; the one you are using should be included in the question as a tag.

Comment: Thanks still learning about posting have done so now!

Comment: You said these tables are (or can be?) linked by the 2 mentioned columns. How does that not satisfy as your "key"? Perhaps you need a full outer join so that you can find those rows in either table that have no "match"? And for the sanity of people that follow you, always define an alias for every table in your query and use it to reference any column. Develop good habits and write code in a consistent fashion - even for simple demos used in public forums like this.

Comment: I should have said "define a short (but useful and not cryptic) alias".

Comment: @Smor do you mean for example LiveRTOLocationErrors E as an alias and then the columns as E.CNTR_ID .... am new to this so a bit less of an abrupt comment would be nice